# How do I integrate $r^3/\sqrt{16+r^2}$ with the tangent identity (arctan)

Tags: calculus

I am having trouble identifying what to do. I get stuck after the first IBP.

$$\int r^{3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{16+r^{2}}} dr$$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: $\int{(\sqrt{16+r^2})'\cdot r^2}.$

Answer (score 2):

$r=4\tan(\theta)$
$$
\begin{align}
\int r^3\frac1{\sqrt{16+r^2}}\,\mathrm{d}r
&=64\int\frac{\tan^3(\theta)}{\sec(\theta)}\mathrm{d}\tan(\theta)\\
&=64\int\tan^3(\theta)\sec(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=64\int\frac{\sin^3(\theta)}{\cos^4(\theta)}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=-64\int\frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{\cos^4(\theta)}\,\mathrm{d}\cos(\theta)\\
&=-64\int\left(\frac1{\cos^4(\theta)}-\frac1{\cos^2(\theta)}\right)\,\mathrm{d}\cos(\theta)\\
&=64\left(\frac1{3\cos^3(\theta)}-\frac1{\cos(\theta)}\right)+C\\[6pt]
&=\frac13\sqrt{16+r^2}^3-16\sqrt{16+r^2}+C\\[9pt]
&=\frac{r^2-32}3\sqrt{16+r^2}+C
\end{align}
$$

---

Alternatively, we could simply use $x=16+r^2$
$$
\begin{align}
\int r^3\frac1{\sqrt{16+r^{2}}}\,\mathrm{d}r
&=\frac12\int\frac{x-16}{\sqrt{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac13x^{3/2}-16x^{1/2}+C\\[3pt]
&=\frac{r^2-32}3\sqrt{16+r^2}+C
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
$$I=\dfrac{1}{2}\int  \dfrac{(r^2+16)-16}{\sqrt{16+r^{2}}} dr^2=\dfrac{1}{2}\int\sqrt{16+t}dt-8\int\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{t+16}},\ \ t:=r^2$$